# ODE with Neumann non-homogeneous boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

ODE:
$$u''(x)=0$$
BCs:
$$u(0)=0$$
$$-ku'(L)=h[u(L)-T_e]$$
Domain:
$$0\leq x \leq L$$
where $T_e$ and $L$ are constants.

This is for an insulated rod, kept at constant temperature at one end and losing convective heat to the environment at the other.

---

The ODE easily solves to:

$u(x)=c_1 x + c_2$

and with the first BC we get $c_2=0$

But applying the second BC leads to a mess and $c_1$ I could not determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second boundary condition requires solving for $c_1$ in the equation
$$-kc_1=h(c_1 L-T_e),$$
so distribute the $h$, bring all terms containing $c_1$ to the LHS and all else to the RHS, yielding
$$h T_e = (hL+k)c_1,$$
so that $c_1 = \frac{h T_e}{k+hL}$.

It is easy to verify that
$u(x)=\frac{h T_e}{(k+hL)} x$ satisfies $u''(x)=0$ and the first BC, $u(0)=0$. Verifying the second BC is just a little more algebra. We will divide by $-k$ in the BC so we must show
$$u'(L)=-\frac{h}{k}(u(L)-T_e).$$

We have
$$u'(L)=\frac{h T_e}{k+hL},$$
so lets just now compute the RHS of the second to last displayed equation
$$-\frac{h}{k}(u(L)-T_e)$$
$$=-\frac{h}{k}\left( \frac{h T_e}{(k+hL)} L-T_e \right)$$
$$=-\frac{h}{k}\left(\frac{-T_e k}{k+hL} \right)$$
$$=\frac{h T_e}{k+hL}=u'(L),$$
as desired.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that myself! Thank you.